# Differences between DomainKeys vs DKIM?

Tags: dkim, domainkeys

Please explain about differences between DomainKeys vs DKIM

Answer (score 37, accepted):

DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) is the successor to Yahoo DomainKeys. Being very similar in functionality to DomainKeys, DKIM has additionally adopted aspects from Cisco’s Identified Internet Mail standard (IIM), and the result has been an enhanced standard that provides more flexibility and security than its predecessor. Some of the differences between DomainKeys and DKIM include:

- Multiple signature algorithms (as opposed to just one available with DomainKeys)
- More options with regard to canonicalization, that validates both header and body
- The ability to delegate signing to third parties
- The ability for DKIM to self-sign the DKIM-Signature header field – to protect against its being modified
- The ability for wildcard option on some parameters
- The ability to support signature timeouts in DNS

http://www.socketlabs.com/articles/show/email-authentication-guide?page=6

Comment: Is it sufficient to configure only dkim, or is it benificial to have a dkim AND a domainkey header in outgoing mails?

Comment: DomainKeys is deprecated and is superseded by DKIM, so having both would not be necessary. Of course, having DKIM and SPF together would be beneficial.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework